# query firebase database by ordering two values in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a database of posts in firebase, and each has a timestamp and a rating. 
i know how to order by time OR by rating, but would it be possible to order by rating, then limit by time. ie. show highest rated posts over the last week?

ie.

```
Ref.queryOrderedByChild("rating").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {...}
```

would order by rating, but how would i then limit the query by time, and not rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Firebase does not support cross referencing nor server-side logic, so you'll probably have to query by the more specific value, pull the data down, then sort the rest client side.

Alternatively, you could also try to get creative with GeoFire (firebase's cross referencing solution for latitude/longitude location querying), though that'll the hackiest solution ever...

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if that was the case. I appreciate the answer!

Comment: Yeah, spent a good few days sleuthing to find out as well. :( Really is a shame.